# Guitar to iPhone JFET pre-amp circuit issue

Tags: audio, circuit-design, ground, schematics, preamp

I am following [this](http://www.planetz.com/assembling-the-idevice-guitar-interface/) tutorial to build a simple JFET pre-amp to connect a guitar to an iphone.

This is the schematic:
[image: The schematic]
I have soldered the components as per the schematic directly onto the 1/4" mono jack for the guitar.

The issue is it only works when I have one finger touching the 3.5mm jack's mic wire/pad and another finger touching the 1/4" tip connection (blue dots on image). Is this an issue with grounding, with the diodes or ...? I am at a loss here.

Comment: The JFET is wired to a fixed-voltage supply. That allows NO OUTPUT VARIATION. I suggest you read up on "phantom power" interfaces.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf:  The "2.8VDC" is just sloppy notation.  The microphone input of an iPhone (or any phone, really) has a small DC voltage on it, but has a series resistor of a couple of k.  The way this circuit is drawn, it works on the assumption that there's that series resistance in the phone.